# Version Lock Ubuntu Repository

Tags: ubuntu, chef, automation

I found some duplicates of this question, but none of them answered exactly the thing I want to try.

I have one QA and one production server managed by chef solo. I want to version lock the apt repository to a specific version, so that i can upgrade to the latest version of a package in my chef recipe.

Is hold on ubuntu the right way to go for that? it seems i need to apply that for every package?

I'm just trying to work out how to update servers with chef in a secure manner. My preference would be I install updates on QA, test if it works, if so lock the repo in production to the same version numbers as on QA, install updates on production. Any other suggestions how to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion would be to create local repositories to overcome this problem. if you want to control the repo you need to maintain your own (RedHat Satellite allows you to this as well, but for rpm's. i'm not aware of such a web based management tool for deb repo's on debian/ubuntu).

you can create as many repos as you want, each could hold different versions and then point servers to the repo you want them to be locked on.

Debian guide on setting up local repos;
https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository

Comment: Hosting an own repository doesn't seem very convenient and we also would need to order a new server for that, so that isn't an option. Isn't it possible to obtain a unique url for the apt repository in it's current state?